# FOSUserBundle extra authentication criteria

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2

I'm working on a multi-tenancy application and I need to accomplish some rules to check when the user can be authenticated (I'm not talking about roles, trying make login should return "Invalid username or password").

My question is: where is the best place to put these additional checks?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to read the User related classes in FosUserBundle.
I have made many chnages by adding custom methods in [UserManager.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/UserManager.php)

FOS call many chained methods you can go through these files and chnage according to your needs

Also look out for

`UserListerner.php` 
`User.php`

Answer (score 1):

That depends on type of checks you intent to perform, but in general the best way is to use a custom security Voter.

There is an example in official documentation showing how to implement IP blacklist:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but still very relevant, I think. The answer helped me in the right path (FOSUserBundle 2.0 with Symfony 3.3) - if someone is still looking, here are more details
https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html

This part was key for me:

> You can replace the default implementation of the user manager by
>   defining a service implementing
>   `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface` and setting its id in the
>   configuration. The id of the default implementation is
>   `fos_user.user_manager.default`
>
> `fos_user:
>       # ...
>       service:
>           user_manager: custom_user_manager_id`
>
> Your custom implementation can extend `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager`
>   to reuse the common logic.

And in my case, I just copied the whole of `FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager` (which extends `FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager`) into my `AppBundle\Services` as my starting point.

I also had to copy the injections from here: `vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine.xml`